# How to debug/test POS, log out the authorityId?

Tags: babe, pos, debug

I am trying to customize the POS. But I don't know how to evaluate my algorithm. I want to print out the authority ID (BABE) and block producer ID.
How do I do that? Please give me some leads.

Thank you so much